# Term for cross-browser/desktop applications?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term that describes applications that can compile as both browser and desktop applications?  An example would be an Adobe Flex application being compiled as a Flash application for display in a browser and also being compiled as an Air application to be run as a desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've somewhere heard something along the lines of "Rich Internet Application with out-of-browser experience/functionality". Wikipedia on Adobe AIR says something like "browser-less RIA".

Comment: We have a knack for the snappy names in the world of software, don’t we?

Comment: @Paul: It gets even worse if you translate them. I'm no native speaker of English but I've long changed to only using software in English just because translated feature names are even more horrible than their original counterparts. There are very few applications that only restrict themselves to domain language.

Answer (score 1):

SAP seized the term "cross-client" for [their own solutions](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/03/28/what-is-cross-client/) and it's a shame.

I think that "*cross-client app*" is the best term (brief but yet comprehensive) to concisely define:

" *an application that can be run as executable in any OS, and as a web app in any browser* ".